# Scrollbar not visible for certain users

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a web app which has a fixed side bar used for navigation. The app is built of [this template](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/)
We are facing a very strange problem where the scroll bar disappears from the html and the page gets cut off. The interesting thing is the scrollbar shows up for 99% of our users but not for the remaining 1%.

We tried everything we could think of including setting the body and html to 100% height and automatic overflow, we also asked those 1% of our users to disable all their browser extensions, clear their cache but nothing helped. 
Those 1% still have scrolling issues and their pages are cut off.

What can cause a scrollbar to disappear for some users but not others?

Comment: expected a better illustration of problem with relevant codes from some one with 13.2K reputation

Comment: I always included code snippets and try my best to explain the problem at hand (you can check all my previous questions) But this one got me lost, my html works fine on most browsers but not for certain users and have no clue where to start :(

Answer (score 1):

Without actually seeing the page, the only thing I can think of is making sure the scrollbar always shows with overflow content like so.

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Some additional research shows that sometimes Firefox doesn't play nice, so you can try this if that's the case.

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Source: https://egilhansen.com/2007/03/28/css-trick-always-show-scrollbars/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I thought of forcing the scrollbar on the users but the app does not look nice and looses some real estate once the scrollbar is there.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? Sometimes if content like h1 tags exceed the container, the content overflows off the page to the side. That might be the issue (local fonts not matching up, causing some slight design issues). Without seeing the page, an issue like this is really tough to diagnose.

Comment: Yes, we are on Bootstrap. Agreed, that's why I came here as a last resort (taking a risk of getting tons of -1 s as I have no clue what to share and what not)